# Simple background image not being applied to parent from a for of loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the probable basic error here. I'm just trying to get the background image to apply to the parent `.img-wrap` class rather than to the image itself.

Adding a background colour works, but the background image fails. Any ideas why?

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrap img');

for (let img of imgs) {
  let imgSrc = img.getAttribute("src");
  img.parentNode.style["background-image"] = imgSrc;
  /* this works: img.parentNode.style["background-color"] = 'blue'; */
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  object-position: -9999px; /* hides image */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.img-wrap {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-wrap'>
  <img src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw5eILfy-c8/maxresdefault.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='img-wrap'>
  <img src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw5eILfy-c8/maxresdefault.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='img-wrap'>
  <img src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw5eILfy-c8/maxresdefault.jpg'>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MNydoe

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `url()` when using the background-image property:

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrap img');

for (let img of imgs) {
  let imgSrc = img.getAttribute("src");
  img.parentNode.style["background-image"] = 'url("' + imgSrc + '")'; // or `url("${imgSrc}")`
  /* this works: img.parentNode.style["background-color"] = 'blue'; */
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  object-position: -9999px; /* hides image */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.img-wrap {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-wrap'>
  <img src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw5eILfy-c8/maxresdefault.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='img-wrap'>
  <img src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw5eILfy-c8/maxresdefault.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='img-wrap'>
  <img src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw5eILfy-c8/maxresdefault.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat by milliseconds, again. :D